# JScrollPane does not scroll with laptop's touchpad

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jscrollpane, touchpad

I have a program that shows text with `JTextArea` in a `JScrollPane`. It works fine with normal mouse, but not with my laptop's touchpad (The touchpad works correctly with other pages).

Is there any difference between the touchpad scrolling and the mouse wheel scrolling in the view of Java? How can I solve this?

Comment: Does scrolling on the touchpad work with Eclipse?

Comment: I don't use any IDE for coding, only Notepad++ and command prompt. (Sorry if I answered wrong, I don't really know what Eclipse is :D)

Comment: Yeah, Eclipse is an IDE. -- I suggest that youedit the question to add OS and its version and the Java version you are using.